# R: Use vector as key parameter in tidyr spread function

Tags: r, data-manipulation, tidyr, spread

I am trying to use tidyr spread function, except I want to pass in my own vector of feature names to be used for the key parameter.

For example, the default usage would be

```
test<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),
             feat=c("feat1", "feat2", "feat1", "feat2"),
             value = c(10,20, 1000, 2000))
test %>% spread(key = feat, value = value, fill = 0)
  id feat1 feat2
1  1    10    20
2  2  1000  2000
```

I would like to pass in my own vector of feature strings to be used as the key, something like this.

```
featlist<-c("feat1", "feat2", "feat3")
test %>% spread(key = featlist, value = value, fill = 0)
#desired output
  id feat1 feat2 feat3
1  1    10    20     0
2  2  1000  2000     0
#Error output
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector
#Trying spread_
test %>% spread_(key = featlist, value = "value", fill = 0)
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

Comment: Keep in mind that I have changed the column type to `character` from `factor` in my answer. I wanted to have a solution which can work on any column types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make that the feat column a factor with levels set to `featlist` then set the `drop` parameter to `FALSE` as in:

```
test<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),
                 feat=c("feat1", "feat2", "feat1", "feat2"),
                 value = c(10,20, 1000, 2000))

featlist<-c("feat1", "feat2", "feat3")
test$feat <- factor(test$feat, levels = featlist)

test %>% spread(key = feat, value = value, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
```

Which results in:

```
  id feat1 feat2 feat3
1  1    10    20     0
2  2  1000  2000     0
```

Comment: This was a frustratingly simple solution. Thank you. Using only pipes: `test %>% mutate(feat = factor(feat, levels = featlist)) %>% spread(feat, value, fill = 0, drop = FALSE) `

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `tidyr::spread` doesn't allow to use your own `vector` as `key` but fortunately `expand.grid` provide you an option to use your own `vector` and expand `data.frame` before calling `spread` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
expand.grid(id=unique(test$id), feat = featlist) %>% #creates all combinations
  mutate(feat = as.character(feat)) %>%  
  left_join(test, by=c("id", "feat")) %>%      #Join with actual dataframe
  spread(key=feat, value = value, fill = 0)

#  id feat1 feat2 feat3
#1  1    10    20     0
#2  2  1000  2000     0
```

**Data:**

```
test<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),
                 feat=c("feat1", "feat2", "feat1", "feat2"),
                 value = c(10,20, 1000, 2000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

featlist<-c("feat1", "feat2", "feat3")
```